# How do LINQ expressions work with Stored Procedures?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures

One of my requirements for a new project I'm working on is that all SQL queries must use stored procedures. I'll be using Entity Framework & the repository pattern to manage data access, and in my repositories I'll have "Find( predicate )" and "FindAll( )" methods. At the moment they are both using the same stored procedure ("select * from Foo").

Seeing as I don't have access to SQL Profiler I'm not quite sure how LINQ expressions would translate in my Find( predicate) method? If I have something like:

```
List<Foo> myFoo = repository.Find( f => f.Country == "Australia" && f.Status = "New" );
```

am I correct in assuming this would retrieve ALL records via the sproc, with the resulting data filtered in-memory? If this is the case, how can I structure the sproc to only retrieve the needed records, while at the same time allowing for the use of linq expressions (needs to allow for &&, ||, != etc)? Is this something that's even possible without having to ditch sprocs?

Comment: It is virtually impossible to effectively use query-composition LINQ and query-sprocs at the same time. You will essentially be using EF as an elaborate way to write the wrapper code around the sprocs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes not much sense to use EF if you are forced to use stored procs for everything. In fact, one of the greatest virtues of EF is that it automatically generate queries, with the rigth number of parameters and the right query sintax to get/insert/update/delete data.

There are two advantages of EF that you'll lose:

- navigation, i.e. easily getting related data, with eager, explicit or lazy loading
- shaped data, i.e. get an entity which has properties which other entities or collections of entities
- automatic generation of simple CRUD operations (inert/update/delete/select). You can specify stoed procs for this operations
- getting the right queries if the database changing simply changing the model (which can be nearly automatic, depending on the way you're using EF) If you'r data changes, you'll have to modify the related stored procs
  *automatic generation of queries for ad hoc filters (filters which has different setof conditions over different columns)

If you don't let EF generate queries, you won't have easy navigation, shaped data, automatic generation of the right queries, and filters, etc. Somefot his will be possible, onlyif you do a really hard work in the models. But some of your changes can be lost if you update your model form the database

If you're using EF, the occasions in which is justified to used stored procs are:

- you need to modify data that can't be directly modified by EF (i.e. updatable queries in older versions of EF were they were not supported)
- you have optimized stored proc that you want to use, instead of the queries generated by EF, i.e. optimized complex filter
- stored procs that makes lots of things (those which are not simple insert/update/delete or select procedures)
- any other occasions in which an stored procedure will offer some advantage over the automatically generated queries.

For all the rest of queries, it's much better lo let EF do the work for you.

If you're required to use stored procs for everything, the advantage of using EF will be the automatic mapping of data to entities, but you'll lost many other advanatges of EF.

You'll have to do this:

- You'll need to define as many entities as different data is returned form the stored procs
- You'll have to map each stored proc to the right entity (they're mapped to functions), to functions, or modifiy the model (edmx) to let it know which procedure to use for insert/update/delete and get

It will be hard to define a model that with relations between entities that have relations between them.

As to the question about `repository.Find(...)` in the best case, you're right, all the data will be queried, and then, filter on the client side. In the worst case, if your model isn't properly defined, it can fail.

If you let EF create the query, it will send the right filter to the DB (in a single case like your sample).
If you have specialized stored procs that filter in specific ways you'll have to forget about LINQ, and call directly the mapped functions.

So, unless there's areally good reason to use SPs, it would be way better to let EF create the queries for you.

Comment: Bit late updating my question but I did some fiddling around and came to the same conclusion. We've dropped the sproc requirement for the time being and will revisit it if performance becomes an issue (doesn't look like it will).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, out of the box what you are doing would retrieve all records and filter in memory.    I wouldn't go as far as saying it's impossible to compose expressions and sprocs, but it's highly impractical and probably defeats the purpose of your sproc requirement in the first place.  You'd have to either interpret the expression tree and generate parameterized sql and pass that to the sproc (probably defeats the purpose of the sproc requirement), or interpret the expression tree and properly pass arguments to a "generic sproc".  "Generic" meaning that it had nullable parameters for anything you'd like to filter on (pretty impractical and will have a lot of limitations - no joins etc).

If you're respecting the sproc requirement, I'd give up on any sort of data access api that exposed IQueryable (You will lose the ablility to compose expressions and sprocs unless you are willing to execute your expressions in memory).

Even without composability between expressions and sprocs, as JotaBe noted, EF will still provide convenience in dealing with models and avoiding rather boilerplate ado.